# Capybara - Clicking a link based another value

Tags: html, css, xpath, hyperlink, capybara

I'm in a bit of a struggle with finding and clicking a specific link.
All links in a HTML table contain the word 'Edit' (it's an 'Edit' link for a configuration setting).
However, the link varies per environment I'm working on, so only the 'Edit' bit of the link is consistent.

In the HTML of the page, I found that this link is part of a table also containing the configuration setting that I want to edit.
I've been struggling for a few hours now to find this link through Xpath, through CSS... Basically I need someone's help on this. Hence my post here!

The HTML of the page looks like this (I anonymized it -- is that even a word?):

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>edit</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Value</th>
       <th>Label</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td><a href="/configurations/406/edit">Edit</a></td>
         <td>Configuration 1</td>
         <td>This is its value</td>
         <td>This is its explanation</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><a href="/configurations/327/edit">Edit</a></td>
         <td>Configuration 2</td>
         <td>This is its value</td>
         <td>This is its explanation</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><a href="/configurations/328/edit">Edit</a></td>
         <td>Configuration 3</td>
         <td>This is its value</td>
         <td>This is its explanation</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Can someone please give me some pointers as to how I can get to each 'Edit' link, based on the 'configuration'?

Thanks a lot in advance. It will really save me a headache!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scope Capybaras finds and actions to other elements, therefore

```
find(:css, 'tr', text: 'Configuration 2').click_link('Edit')
```

would click the edit link inside the tr that includes the text 'Configuration 2'

Comment: Thanks so much.. I know this was a beginner's question.. But oh the struggle! This worked like a charm, I'll never forget it! Cheers!